# How does the pairing work on Lightsaber Escape work

Tags: android, ios, mobile, browser, pairing

How does the pairing work on something like this? https://lightsaber.withgoogle.com/

Here's another example: http://sheav.se/en

I want to be able to link a mobile app to a desktop web browser using a 4-digit unique pairing code, but I have no idea what to even Google!

Comment: Might want to look at: https://www.chromeexperiments.com/mobile-controller?page=0&sort=newest https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket?hl=en and https://youtu.be/17P67Uz0kcw - so you are looking for websockets.

Comment: Ahh, websockets! Thank you so much for those links! Time to journey down the Google rabbit hole...